# Understanding InetAddress

Tags: java

I have this code.It works fine.But I don't understand the meaning of few lines of code.I have written comments next to lines I'm unable to understand.Can anyone please help me with understanding these lines.Thanks in advance :)

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Netaddress
{
    public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception
      {
          InetAddress c;      //this line
          c =InetAddress.getLocalHost();   //and this one
          System.out.println("Local Address Is :"+c);
          System.out.println("Done!");
      }
}
```

Comment: It is somewhat hard to understand what you don't understand. The first line is a variable declaration, the second sets this variable to the local host address.

Comment: Yeah but InetAddress is a class ,how is this declaration possible? Thats what I don't understand.can you explain that?

Comment: It declares `c` to be a variable that can hold references to instances of class `InetAddress`. It is not initialized by this declaration.

Comment: still I don't get it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InetAddress` is a class in Java (java.net package).
From the javadoc of [getLocalHost](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost()) (**emphasis mine**)

> Returns the **address of the local host**. This is achieved by retrieving the name of the host from the system, then resolving that name into an InetAddress.
>   Note: The resolved address may be cached for a short period of time.
>   
>  
> If there is a security manager, its checkConnect method is called with the local host name and -1 as its arguments to see if the operation is allowed. If the operation is not allowed, an InetAddress representing the loopback address is returned.